# How to adjust seaboarn annotation so that it won't overlap?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am having a chart as below plot by seaboarn.heatmap. How can I adjust the chart so that I won't have the annotation overlap with each other?
[image: bo]

Comment: That picture is kind of messed up

Comment: Try either using a larger figure size or try reducing the font size of the annotations. I don't see any other way. Either you increase one or decrease the other

Comment: Converted to answer

Comment: As @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest once said, if you want to fit an elephant in the refrigerator, either get a big refrigerator or shrink the elephant and make it the size of a mouse ;)